# Settings KVM on Atom processor

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I will set up KVM on Atom-Server. But I'm wordering is it possible to running KVM on ATOM-processer ? ( in ATOM-server processor )

Comment: For future reference it wouldn't hurt if you would also specify the exact CPU model that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run KVM, your Intel processor must support hardware virtualization, i.e. has the VT-x feature. Only a very few recently released Atom processors have support for hardware virtualization, and yours is probably not among them.

If you already have Linux installed, you can check the output from `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and make sure the `flags` contain `vmx`. If they do, then you have hardware virtualization and you can use KVM. If they do not, then you can't.

Or you can look up your specific model of Atom processor at [Intel's Ark web site](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/29035) and see if it has *"Intel® Virtualization Technology (VT-x)"*.

Comment: Ok. I checked that atom processor ( for server ) support 'intel-VTx' so I guess it can support KVM. But as I know, to running KVM it has to support additional virtualization technologys. ( like PTE ?) , but atom processor dosen't support PTE. right?

Comment: I've never heard of "PTE" so I don't know what you mean by that. If you truly have hardware virtualization as described above, this is all you really need.

Comment: Oh, I'sorry, that is EPT(Extended Page Table) tech...

Comment: No, you don't need extended page tables, though you would get better performance if you had it.

Comment: I will try migration KVM's VM on Atom board. But now, I don't have atom processor machine.. ;-( so I'm wondering it is possible migration on ATOM processor.